# Как получить Cookie с сайта по умолчанию C#

Tags: c#, cookie, browsers

Скажите как можно получить cookie с сайта (cookie находятся в браузере chrome) средствами c#. Нужно получить те cookie которые используються браузером. То есть если пользователь через Chrome авторизирован на моём сайте, то программа получает cookie авторизированого пользователя.

Comment: Если сайт ваш то `string id =HttpContext.Request.Cookies["id"].Value; `. Ну и настройки OWIN pipeline  и т.п. для обработки кук. Но кажется это работает только для своих собственных кук, которые ты должен сам и установить (неуверен)

Comment: А в направлении selenium что-то пробовали?

Comment: Я слышал о selenium. Но не подскажете как использовать?

Comment: @Wheelys нужно скачать selenium web driver подключить ее как библиотеку к проекту, затем скачать selenium chrome driver, есть так же драйвер для Firefox (остальные не использовал) и запустить, он запуститься на определенном порту, в проекте при подключении нужно указать порт. Примеры подключения в коде можно посмотреть в интернете их там полно. http://executeautomation.com/blog/functional-tools/selenium-automation-with-c/